# Xcode always compile CocoaPods libraries whenever I build my project. (Long compile time)

Tags: swift, xcode, cocoapods, compiler-optimization, ios14

Whenever I build my project with any change it starts compiling the `cocoapods` libraries.

I have already tried this:

https://github.com/leavez/cocoapods-binary

But, not all my dependencies support it. So I don't want to use it and also I don't want to shift from `cocoapods` to cartage. Is there any other good solution to optimize compile time of my project?

Comment: You can have a separate project that will produce a framework and integrate it into your app?

Comment: @sloik but don't you think, it will increase the size of the project. I am using 39 pods

Comment: try and compare :)

Comment: @sloik what do you mean by  "separate project that will produce a framework and integrate it into your app" can you enlighten me more about the process. Thankyou

Comment: @YaseenMajeed  Project -> https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/creating-an-xcode-project-for-an-app Target -> https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/ToolsLanguages/Conceptual/Xcode_Overview/WorkingwithTargets.html

Integration -> https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPFrameworks/Tasks/IncludingFrameworks.html